# Jquery disable all <Select's> within the same <li> as clicked Checkbox

Tags: jquery

**Jquery onclick checkbox disable all < Select > within the same < li >**

here is my html

```
<li class="list-group-item bs-callout bs-callout-active">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="days" value="1" > 
  </div>
  <div>
    Monday
  </div>
  <div>
    <select><option>Value</option></select>
  </div>
  <div> until </div> 
  <div>
    <select><option>Value</option> </select>
  </div>
</li>
```

My Jquery code so far:

```
$(".days").on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
{  ... } else
{ $(this).parent().parent().$("[select]").prop('disabled',true);  }
```

Not working. i would prefer the best combination between "speed and writing it generic" (no id) because there are lot more lines and i think i want to avoid different classes for each day/line. i got already a generic class for the checkbox and want to walk from there to the selectboxes.

```
$(".class").prop('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect selector to target select element. use:

```
$(this).closest('li').find("select").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: `.prop('disabled', true);` is 'better' (preferred)

Comment: because of HTML spec, `disabled` is a boolean attribute. `.prop('disabled', 'disabled')` works because string `disabled` is truly in javascript